# QMenu derived client cant able to call the addMenu funtion

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am trying to call the addMenu of QMenu using derived class pointer but throwing error, cn someone point the error

```
csMenu * editMenu = new csMenu();

QMenu *preferenceMenu = new QMenu();
preferenceMenu->addAction(new QAction(tr("&Split Plot"), this));
preferenceMenu->addAction(new QAction(tr("&Split "), this));
editMenu->addMenu(preferenceMenu);

QFont font("Segoe UI", 12);//Museo Sans 500
preferenceMenu->setFont(font);
```

Font also not setting for Sub menu

Comment: I got the solution, It was inheriting the Parent property

Comment: Please consider creating an answer yourself.